# No logro clonar el repositorio y instalarle todas las dependencias necesarias

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Tengo el siguiente problema cuando creo una imagen propia necesitaria que me levante el repositorio gestion y que me instale todo el resto de cosas que hago yo pero cuando creo la imagen y despues la levanto la imagen esta vacia nose porque pasa esto soy muy nuevo en docker.

tengo el siguiente codio yo en la carpeta /docker/ cuento con los siguientes archivos el Dockerfile y el docker-composer.yml y aparte de la carpeta gestion entonces para resumir tengo

```
/docker/: Dockerfile
          docker-composer.yml
          gestion
```

el Dockerfile tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
ARG user
ARG uid
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

RUN chomd 777 -R -c /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www


USER $user
```

DESPUES EN  docker-composer.yml declare el volumen de esta manera

```
 app:
    build:
      args:
        user: master
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: gestionadmin
    container_name: gestionadmin-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./gestionadmin/:/var/www
      - ./gestionadmin/public:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - gestionadmin
```

Comment: cuando ejecutas docker-compose build que pasa? No veo el puerto

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de como yo lo tengo donde tengo dockercompose.yml porfuera y una carpeta api donde esta el proyecto y dockerfile adentro           
 api:
    image: api
    build: ./api
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/
      - ./api/public/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8200:80